# Volume control not functioning

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

I noticed a few weeks ago that my system volume control doesn't affect my volume. It's stuck at max which isn't terrible but it does get irritating when I run multiple applications and have to change the volume for each one so that I don't go completely deaf. In regards to fixing this, I've done clean installs of all my audio drivers. The only thing I'm not willing to do is a complete reinstall of windows (not worth the effort for this IMO)

Comment: So you *can* adjust the volume slider, but it makes no difference in volume?

Comment: Yup, I can even change it in the volume mixer and it won't make any difference. The only way I can change it is the physical dial on my headphones and in-software volume options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a driver issue, and this can be hard to fix, especially for us since you kind of forgot to mention what soundcard you have.

Anyway, you should use add/remove programs to remove the drivers completely, then go into the device manager, rightclick the audio drivers, select uninstall.

Then reboot the system.

Install the drivers for your soundcard.

Reboot again.

Test if it works.

Usually the problem is that it doesn't delete the old drivers and as such reuses them. This causes the problem to not be fixed.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have the sabertooth 990FX onboard sound system (Realtek High Definition Audio w/ driver version 6.0.1.7083). I've done a full clean reinstall of every audio driver with reboots post uninstall and install to no avail. I've also reinstalled (properly) my Astro headphone software but that didn't fix it either. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your chipset drivers? They're responsible for communicating with the soundcard driver. After reinstalling the chipset, reinstall the audio drivers again. (also obviously, reboot in the process as many times as needed.

Comment: I have not. I'll give it a shot when I get home from work.

Comment: Turns out that the issue actually came from a program I use called "Unified Remote". I was fiddling with the settings and found out that they have an 'Override hardware default sound settings' option and that was screwing with my computer. I'll give you the answer though since that's usually the correct course of action :P